# Check if file exists in HDFS path?

Tags: scala, hadoop

How can I check if a file exists given a certain base path. I am providing the method a file list for example:
file1.snappy, file2,snappy,...

I need to check if file exists in either of the given paths for example: `hdfs://a/b/c/source/file1.snappy` or if file exists in `hdfs://a/b/c/target/file1.snappy`. How can I update/modify the method below to accept `/a/b/c/target/` or `/a/b/c/source/` as a basepath and check if file exists? If it exists in source add to a sourceList and if it is in destination add to a destination list.

```
  val fs = FileSystem.get(sprk.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

  def fileExists(fileList:Array[String]) : Boolean = {
    var fileNotFound = 0
    fileList.foreach{
      file => {
        if(!fs.exists(new Path(file)))  fileNotFound+=1
        print("fileList",file)
      }
    }
    if(fileNotFound > 0) {
      println(fileNotFound + ": number of files not found probably moved")
      false
    }
    else
      true
  }
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Boolean true or false, based on if file exists in source or target. I can call the method twice that's not a concern. @Srinivas

Comment: @coderWorld it exactly works with your s3 requirement as per my exp. and test case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a source dir and target are like this below example
[image]

try this way for recursive lookup

`URI.create(... )` is very imp when you are dealing with s3 objects (will also works with hdfs / local fs)

```
import java.net.URI

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, LocatedFileStatus, Path, RemoteIterator}
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
/**
    * getAllFiles - get all files recursively from the sub folders.
    * 
    * @param path String
    * @param sc SparkContext
    * @return Seq[String]
    */
  def getAllFiles(path: String, sc: SparkContext): Seq[String] = {
    val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
    val fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(path), conf)
    val files: RemoteIterator[LocatedFileStatus] = fs.listFiles(new Path(path), true) // true for recursive lookup
    val buf = new ArrayBuffer[String]
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      val fileStatus = files.next();
      buf.append(fileStatus.getPath().toString)
    }
    buf.toSeq
  }
```

***Example usage  :***

```
 val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName(getClass.getName)
    .master("local[*]").getOrCreate


  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  val myfiles: Seq[String] = getAllFiles("data/test_table", sc)
  myfiles.foreach(println)
  println(myfiles.contains("/data/test_table/source/part-00000-19b67f0c-3fb0-4718-8a31-ac770e2dc0ba-c000.snappy.parquet"))
```

Result :

```
/data/test_table/target/part-00000-9205704a-cb0c-4933-87d4-c21313e76297-c000.snappy.parquet
/data/test_table/target/part-00000-19b67f0c-3fb0-4718-8a31-ac770e2dc0ba-c000.snappy1111.parquet
/data/test_table/target/part-00000-9205704a-cb0c-4933-87d4-c21313e76297-c000.snappy11.parquet
/data/test_table/source/part-00000-19b67f0c-3fb0-4718-8a31-ac770e2dc0ba-c000.snappy1.parquet
/data/test_table/source/part-00000-19b67f0c-3fb0-4718-8a31-ac770e2dc0ba-c000.snappy111.parquet
/data/test_table/source/part-00000-19b67f0c-3fb0-4718-8a31-ac770e2dc0ba-c000.snappy.parquet


true
```

Comment: imports were added

Comment: Also my method expects List:Array[String] as a parameter. But yours is just a String.

Comment: Updated the question slightly, what if instead of just returning True or False I need to add these elments in a sourceList or destinationList, depending on if the path contains source or target?

Comment: these are minute/minor things you can adjust as per your needs. but grab main concept of how to do it. Hope you understood the theme

Comment: Good. Generic solution ..it can work for both HDFS & S3 .. mine is only work for HDFS.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Updated code to work for `hdfs` & `s3`.

Please check below code.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path, RemoteIterator}
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

// For converting to scala Iterator
implicit def convertToScalaIterator[T](remoteIterator: RemoteIterator[T]): Iterator[T] = {
    case class wrapper(remoteIterator: RemoteIterator[T]) extends Iterator[T] {
      override def hasNext: Boolean = remoteIterator.hasNext
      override def next(): T = remoteIterator.next()
    }
    wrapper(remoteIterator)
}

import java.net.URI

def fs(path: String) = FileSystem.get(URI.create(path),spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path, RemoteIterator}
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
convertToScalaIterator: [T](remoteIterator: org.apache.hadoop.fs.RemoteIterator[T])Iterator[T]
fs: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem = org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem@640517de
```

**Sample Directories**

```
scala> "tree /tmp/examples".!
/tmp/examples

0 directories, 0 files

scala> "tree /tmp/sample".!
/tmp/sample
├── aaa
│   └── sample.json
├── bbb
│   └── bbb.json
├── ccc
└── ddd

4 directories, 2 files
```

**Result**

````
scala> List("/tmp/sample","/tmp/examples")
.flatMap(dir => {
    fs(dir)
    .listFiles(new Path(dir),true)
    .toList
    .filter(_.isFile)
    .map(d => (d.getPath.getParent,d.getPath))
// If you want only Boolean values, May be change above line to ```.map(d => (d.getPath.getParent,d.isFile))``` 
})
.foreach(println)

(/tmp/sample/bbb,file:/tmp/sample/bbb/bbb.json)
(/tmp/sample/aaa,file:/tmp/sample/aaa/sample.json)
````

Comment: I think this may not work with s3 files Rams answer may work

Comment: Thanks, I have updated code & Now it will work for both ```hdfs``` & ```s3```.

Comment: While I'm not a fan of implicits, this is a nice solution, especially as the listFiles is very efficient for S3 (async prefetch of next page of results). Tip: If you call toString() on the iterator in Hadoop 3.3.1 it also gives you stats on the number of LIST calls and their latencies.